# Spring Data Redis: Redis Pipeline hget returning always null

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

```
getRedisTemplate().executePipelined(
    new RedisCallback<Object>() { 
        @Override
        public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
            connection.hGet(key);

            return null;
        }
    }
);
```

The result is `null`, and I can not fix it.

Comment: my question is same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323026/spring-data-redis-redis-pipeline-returning-always-null

Comment: i use spring-boot-starter-data-redis 2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

hGet return null when key or field do not exists or when used in pipeline / transaction.
[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisHashCommands.html#hGet-byte:A-byte:A-) it is.
You can use lua script instead.

```
String script = "local a = redis.call('hget','KEYS1','FIELD1')\n"+
                                        "if a then\n"+
                                        "   return redis.call('hincrby','KEYSAND'..a,'FIELD2',1)\n"+
                                        "end";
                                connection.eval(script.getBytes(), ReturnType.INTEGER, 0);
```